# Dibujar la media en un grafico con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el gáfico he dibujado la línea de los valores (azul) de la tabla y, en color rojo, he puesto el valor medio de la columna **Visits** hecho con un bucle:

```
media = visitsPerDay['Visits'].mean()

mediaArr = []
for i in range(len(visitsPerDay)):
    mediaArr.append(media)

plt.plot( visitsPerDay['Day'], visitsPerDay['Visits'], 'b-', visitsPerDay['Day'], mediaArr, 'r-')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede, sólamente con el valor de la media, dibujarla tal y como sale en el gráfico? O tengo que crear un un array obligatoriamente?

Comment: Usa `axline`, por ejemplo: `plt.axhline(y=media, color='r', linestyle='-')`

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias :D